# PHP/SQL Single Page Views Counter

Tags: php, sql, view, count

Hey guys, I was looking for a good answer some hours now but can't find what I'm looking for!

If I have a dynamic Website (maybe news) I got the following links

> ../domain.com/?newsid=1
>
> ../domain.com/?newsid=2
>
> ../domain.com/?newsid=3 etc..

now I would have a individual counter for each of this page..

So I would check every single visitor and if someone is reading the "news 1" 20 times it also should count only 1 time. => Maybe with IP or Cookie.

It should be a function that I can include into the php code like `<? pageviews(ID)?>`

I never thougth anything like this. Hope someone can help me and give me some tips how I can code a script like this (I'm php newbie btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using a counter field in your news table such that when someone opens ?newsid=1 for example, you do this:

```
$newsid = intval($_GET['newsid']);
mysql_query("UPDATE news set counter=counter+1 WHERE id=$newsid");
```

Comment: Hey, yeah but how can I check if the user is a "new visitor" or already read this news in the last hours?

Comment: You can do it by sessions, like this for example: $_SESSION["news_$newsid"] = true; and check to see if it is true, do not update database

Comment: aber a bit brainstorming => and whats happen if someone blocked cookies?

Comment: this way that person is counted more than once, as an alternative you can save IPs, but after some time, database will be so huge

Comment: IPs are often (the most time) avaiable for 24for hour.. I could delete all IPs older than 24 hours with a cronjob.. so I've to creat a table "newsid, ip, time" but I don't know how to combine all these practise to a working script

Answer (score 1):

i found a great article on http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-a-simple-pageviews-counter-using-php-and-mysql.php let me short the code create a table with rows count and page and then write this code

```
$user_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$check_ip = mysql_query("select userip from pageview where page='yourpage' and userip='$user_ip'");
if(mysql_num_rows($check_ip)>=1)
{

}
else
{
  $insertview = mysql_query("insert into pageview values('','yourpage','$user_ip')");

    $updateview = mysql_query("update totalview set totalvisit = totalvisit+1 where page='yourpage' ");
}
```